# imap_open() says "invalid remote specification" and fails to connect

Tags: php, imap

When I try to use `imap_open` I get the following error:

```
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {mail.domain.com:110/pop3/novalidate-cert/} in /path/to/mailbox.php on line 5
Can't open mailbox {mail.domain.com:110/pop3/novalidate-cert/}: invalid remote specification
```

My `phpinfo` says that I have:

```
IMAP c-Client Version   2007e
SSL Support             enabled
Kerberos Support        enabled
```

On another server that gives the same `phpinfo` for `imap` it works, although that version is `2006`. PHP says it was compiled with the following settings:

```
'./configure' '--disable-path-info-check' '--enable-exif' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pgsql=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-ttf' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that if you put a trailing `/` after an option like `ssl` or `novalidate-cert` you get a `remote specification error`. **Remove the trailing `/`, and it works!**